# How to modify my vertically collapsible content panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

The original version of `Accordion` supports horizontal collapsible content panels: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp.

I created a jsfiddle for **vertically** collapsible content panels:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9GLR/478/

This is what I was able to do.

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#e9eaed;
}
.content {
  width:960px;
  height:0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.panel-group {
  width:430px;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: right top;
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform-origin: right top;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.panel-heading {
  width: 430px;
}
.panel-title {
  height:18px
}
.panel-title a {
  float:right;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 430px;
  margin: -10px -430px;
}
.panel-body {
  height:830px;
}
.panel-group img {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.panel-group p {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.panel-group .panel img {
  margin-left:400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Accordion 1
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>
                <h1>Title1</h1>
                <br>11A paragraph of text about something pertinant to the site which people could read should the feel the need to read about it. They could skip it as well but this keeps the initial view a good deal less text heavy, see?
                <br>- Some Source
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                Accordion 2
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>
                <h1>Title2</h1>
                <br>
                  22A paragraph of text about something pertinant to the site which people could read should the feel the need to read about it. They could skip it as well but this keeps the initial view a good deal less text heavy, see?
                <br>- Some Source
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to achieve the following behavior: the content panel `Accordion1` should be opened when a page is loaded. It should occupy all screen. But when a user clicks on `Accordion2`, then each content panel occupies 50%. How can I do it? I was thinking that maybe for such behaviour `Accordion1` can be actually substituted by a fixed `div`.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: As you know, the original Accordion allows horizontal content panels. I converted them into vertical ones. But I don't know how to solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: Then this isn't the place to ask. If you don't know how to start, then either do some tutorials to learn or pay a someone to do it for you. This isn't a coding service. You need to do your research and make a good attempt at writing it yourself.  See [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Also, you should include your code directly in the question - external links are not actually allowed on Stack Overflow without also being accompanied with the relevant content here, as the can be removed or changed rendering the question useless to future users. Please see [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some script for your accordion:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
    $('#accordion .panel-heading').on('click', function(e) {
        $('body').addClass('accordion-clicked');
    });
});
```

Than some styles to support it:

```
#accordion .panel .panel-body {
    height: 40vw;
    width: 100vh;
}
#accordion .panel:nth-child(1) .panel-body {
    height: 80vw;
}
.accordion-clicked #accordion .panel:nth-child(1) .panel-body {
    height: 40vw;
}
```

You can adjust the values. Working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9GLR/481/).

Comment: It looks quite nice. By the way is it possible to rotate the text inside the content panel, so that it is horizontal?

Comment: You should not do it this way from start. Transformed elements keep occupying the space in browser and you cannot control it. You have to create a horizontal accordion other way, try searching the google for appropriate jQuery plugins (there are many).

Comment: No, I want accordion to be vertical as it is now. Just only the textual content should be horizontal. Does it mean that I cannot use accordion to accomplish this goal?

Comment: I understand what you want, but you are doing it wrong way. Applying transforms on elements **do not** change their positions, only the browser display. Go on and search for another accordion.

Comment: Probably you mean something like this? http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/

Comment: Something similar, you need the on that opens on click (not on hover). Something like [this one](http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Simple-Vertical-Horizontal-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-asAccordion.html).